# What does the XCOPY /v switch do in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

The **XCOPY** microsoft [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/289483) states that

```
/v  Verifies each new file.
```

Is the verification is md5 checksum or the contents of the file are matched against the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Current documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) says

> /v     Verifies each file as it is written to the destination file to make sure that the destination files are identical to the source files.

It mentions nothing about a checksum or the contents of the file; it simply makes sure that the size of the destination file is the same as that of the source file.

The documentation you linked is clearly outdated, as it discusses xcopy, xcopy32, and Windows ME.

Answer (score -1):

This is what `xcopy /?` output on my screen (*Win7 x64*):

```
/V           Verifies the size of each new file.
```

So, apparently it checks the file size.